# CSS File seem not referenced after publiching to local server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I developed an intranet based application with asp.net mvc 4. I build/published the file using file system publish method then moved the published file to the server (Server 2012) which runs on sql server 2012. As usual, I enabled Windows authentication, enabled directory browsing and created a separate appPool for the application using the integrated pipeline and local system as identity. I then liked the application to it's appPool. On browsing the application, it is viewing as though the css file is missing.

Below is my html view referecing the css and js files when viewd from my application:

```
<!-- core CSS -->
<link href="/Content/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/css/responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- core JS -->
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/main.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/html5shiv.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

And below is the html view of the application after publishing. The CSS file seem not to be referenced. The js files too seem not to be referenced.

```
<!-- core CSS -->
<link href="/TBC2015Live/Content/css?v=9rtONLVCUCbRdiqwPX0SXmvkuPX-D8w3c-hnpsaUERI1" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- core JS -->
<script src="/TBC2015Live/bundles/modernizr?v=wBEWDufH_8Md-Pbioxomt90vm6tJN2Pyy9u9zHtWsPo1"></script>
<script src="/TBC2015Live/bundles/jquery?v=DuNp63axKEm__mWBxQ-SlhlM2syuEL8qBaUB-hzYBAc1"></script>
<script src="/TBC2015Live/bundles/jqueryval?v=NOVQDySGO89wzMzO5x7mWS4C_uAdynpZe_Lk2y-xEM41"></script>
<script src="/TBC2015Live/bundles/bootstrap?v=2Fz3B0iizV2NnnamQFrx-NbYJNTFeBJ2GM05SilbtQU1"></script>
```

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: Have you inspected your HTML code? Check for missing css files. Make sure your CSS files are correctly uploaded.

Comment: All the css files are correctly uploaded. I checked the published files to see if the css files were included....and yes they were.

Comment: if you look at the source code of the page, does the src attribute in your link tag match the path to where your css files are located?  A lot of the time it's because would have a forward slash (for example: "/ccs/mystyles.css" should be "css/mystyles.css"

Comment: @dave: I have just added the source code for the portion referencing the css and js files.

Comment: What if you remove the forward slash from the beginning of the href path.  Does that fix it?  like this... 'href="Content/css/main.css" '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I republished the application in debug mode to my local server and it worked like a charm. All CSS and JS files were referenced correctly.